# Correct labelling of confusion matrix axis

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have written the following code to generate a confusion matrix

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
mnb=MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X_train,Y_train)
sms2="REMINDER FROM O2: To get 2.50 pounds free call credit and details of great offers pls reply 2 this text with your valid name, house no and postcode"
sms="You’ve Won!"
X_test = [str (item) for item in X_test]

Y_pred = mnb.predict(vec.transform(X_test))
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
mat = confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred)
print(mat)
names =[ "non-spam", "spam"]
print(names)
sns.heatmap(mat, square=True, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar=False,
            xticklabels=names, yticklabels=names)
plt.xlabel('Actual [Truth]')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()
```

It generated the following confusion matrix:

[image]

I am not sure if the axis are labelled correctly 
ie. If the x-axis should be Actual and y-axis should be predicted
or the other way around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the scikit=learn documentation, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html, the first call parameter should be the ground truth values, and the second call parameter should be the predicted values via the classifier.

If that is the case, then the return parameter for the confusion matrix should have the rows containing the  true classes and the columns should be the predicted classes.

I think your labels are backward based on that. See also the example https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_display_object_visualization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-display-object-visualization-py